# Control / view Ubuntu screen from Android phone in LAN

Tags: android, linux, wireless, gnome

I'm looking for a way to control my Linux (Ubuntu) screen from my Android phone (e.g. if I was watching a movie and change room I would be able to continue watching it from my Android phone) while being connected to the same network.

I know software like Teamviewer (which uses a remote server that I don't need in this case) etc..., but I would like to use one o more open source applications for the purpose.

What options di I have?

Thanks

Comment: [VNC apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc#group_655) come to mind. A VNC server for your Linux machine is available in the default repos. For FOSS apps, concentrate on those from F-Droid or from my repo, both recognizable by the icons next to the names. [MultiVNC](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.coboltforge.dontmind.multivnc/) might be a good candidate. Or [bVNC](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.iiordanov.freebVNC).

Comment: Good question! VNC works but is a bit laggy and does not provide sound (?).